# WordPress Radio Boxes - selects only the last one

Tags: wordpress, radio-button, wordpress-theming, checked

So I have a form as shown bellow. its a bit long. It contains three radio boxes. Every time I select one, doesn't matter which, and then hit submit, the last radio element shows up as selected instead of the one I clicked. I var dump the option (in this case aisis_core['display_rows']) and it will say the value of the radio element i selected instead of the current on selected.

So I select lists, it will show lists but the radio box selected is no_posts. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 <form action="options.php" method="post">
   <input type='hidden' name='option_page' value='aisis_options' /><input type="hidden"
   name="action" value="update" /><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce"
   value="f0385965c6" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value=
   "/WordPressDev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=aisis-core-options&amp;settings-updated=true" />
     <fieldset>
       <div class="control-group">
         <label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="rows" class="display" name=
         "aisis_core[display_rows]" value="display_rows" checked="checked" /> Display
         posts as rows. <a href="#radioRows" data-toggle="modal"></a></label>

         <div class="control-group">
           <label class="radio"><input type="radio" class="display" name=
           "aisis_core[display_rows]" value="list" checked="checked" /> Display posts a
           list. <a href="#radioLists" data-toggle="modal"></a></label>
         </div>

         <div class="control-group">
           <label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="noDisplay" class="display" name=
           "aisis_core[display_rows]" value="no_posts" checked="checked" /> Display no
           posts.</label>

           <div class="no_posts_section borderBottom">
             <div class="well headLine">
               <h1>Display No Rows</h1>

               <p>If you choose to display no rows please give me a url of the page or
               content you would like to display instead.</p>

               <p class="text-info"><strong>Note:</strong> Formatting of said content is
               up you. All we do is display it.</p>
             </div>

             <div class="control-group">
               <div class="controls">
                 <input type="url" name="aisis_core[index_page_no_posts]" value=
                 "http://google.ca" placeholder="Url" />
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>

           <div class="control-group">
             <div class="form-actions">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </fieldset>
   </form>
```

The function I am using from wordpress is:

```
checked('radio_box_value', isset($options['display_rows']), false)
```

**Note:** radio_box_value is replaced with what ever the value of the radio box is.

In this case only the last radio box has the "checked" in it's tag, when it should be which ever one I chose.

**How are the elements being created?**

The following is how I create the elements, they print out what you see above in the html for the radio buttons. These are done similar to, but not exactly, zend framework.

Its pretty straight forward what were doing, create the element, add the options to the element and then return it.
I hope this gives a better picture as to how these are being created.

```
protected function _radio_rows_element(){
    $options = get_option('aisis_core');
    echo $options['display_rows'];
    $radio_element = array(
        'name' => 'aisis_core[display_rows]',
        'value' => 'display_rows',
        'class' => 'display',
        'id' => 'rows',
        'checked' => checked('display_rows', isset($options['display_rows']) && $options['display_rows'] == 'display_rows', false),
        'label' => ' Display posts as rows. <a href="#radioRows" data-toggle="modal">
            <i class="icon-info-sign"> </i></a>'        
    );

    $radio = new CoreTheme_Form_Elements_Radio($radio_element, $this->sub_section_rows_array());

    return $radio;
}

protected function _radio_list_element(){
    $options = get_option('aisis_core');
    echo $options['display_rows'];
    $radio_element = array(
            'name' => 'aisis_core[display_rows]',
            'value' => 'list',
            'class' => 'display',
            'checked' => checked('list', isset($options['display_rows']) && $options['display_rows'] == 'list', false),
            'label' => ' Display posts a list. <a href="#radioLists" data-toggle="modal">
            <i class="icon-info-sign"> </i></a>'
    );

    $radio = new CoreTheme_Form_Elements_Radio($radio_element);
    return $radio;
}

protected function _radio_no_posts_element(){
    $options = get_option('aisis_core');
    echo $options['display_rows'];
    $radio_element = array(
            'name' => 'aisis_core[display_rows]',
            'value' => 'no_posts',
            'class' => 'display',
            'id' => 'noDisplay',
            'checked' => checked('no_posts', isset($options['display_rows']) && $options['display_rows'] == 'no_posts', false),
            'label' => ' Display no posts.</a>'
    );

    $radio = new CoreTheme_Form_Elements_Radio($radio_element, $this->_sub_section_now_posts_array());
    return $radio;
}
```

Comment: Hi, try removing the checked="checked" from each box declaration.

Comment: thats actually being done from the method I showed.....Which is another reason I posted here. the function I showed is what prints this out.

Comment: in: checked('no_posts', isset($options['display_rows']), false) why do you put "isset", which is the meaning of that second parameter? If is the value of the option so can be checked or not, put only $options['display_rows']

Comment: @gsc-leticia the code has been updated to reflect this, if you are fammilar with arrays you will know that if the 'display_rows' is not set it will throw a warning. hence the isset. we make sure there is a value before we do anything. Hope that explains more. The echo is there to show me whats in each of these - debugging purposes.

Comment: yes, check Mark answer, the problem is that maybe the value to pass isn't True or False, but the value it self

Comment: @gsc-leticia I tried his answer and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to write this:

```
public function set_element_checked($value, $option, $key){
    $options = get_option($option);
    if(isset($options[$key]) && $options[$key] == $value){
        return 'checked';
    }
}
```

which does exactly what I want. compare the element value to that of the $option[$key] and if they match return checked. can be called via:

```
'checked' => set_element_checked('display_rows', 'aisis_core', 'display_rows');
```

Answer (score 1):

"checked" function seems to need the value as second parameter as is explained here  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

Try like this:

```
protected function _radio_rows_element(){
    $options = get_option('aisis_core');
    echo $options['display_rows'];
    $radio_element = array(
        'name' => 'aisis_core[display_rows]',
        'value' => 'display_rows',
        'class' => 'display',
        'id' => 'rows',
        'checked' => checked('display_rows', (isset($options['display_rows']))?$options['display_rows']:'', false),
        'label' => ' Display posts as rows. <a href="#radioRows" data-toggle="modal">
            <i class="icon-info-sign"> </i></a>'        
    );

    $radio = new CoreTheme_Form_Elements_Radio($radio_element, $this->sub_section_rows_array());

    return $radio;
}

protected function _radio_list_element(){
    $options = get_option('aisis_core');
    echo $options['display_rows'];
    $radio_element = array(
            'name' => 'aisis_core[display_rows]',
            'value' => 'list',
            'class' => 'display',
            'checked' => checked('list',(isset($options['display_rows']))?$options['display_rows']:'', false),
            'label' => ' Display posts a list. <a href="#radioLists" data-toggle="modal">
            <i class="icon-info-sign"> </i></a>'
    );

    $radio = new CoreTheme_Form_Elements_Radio($radio_element);
    return $radio;
}

protected function _radio_no_posts_element(){
    $options = get_option('aisis_core');
    echo $options['display_rows'];
    $radio_element = array(
            'name' => 'aisis_core[display_rows]',
            'value' => 'no_posts',
            'class' => 'display',
            'id' => 'noDisplay',
            'checked' => checked('no_posts', (isset($options['display_rows']))?$options['display_rows']:'', false),
            'label' => ' Display no posts.</a>'
    );

    $radio = new CoreTheme_Form_Elements_Radio($radio_element, $this->_sub_section_now_posts_array());
    return $radio;
}
```

This will not give warning when isn't declared the variable $options['display_rows'] (that as you said is a possibility in your case) and will pass the value to the WordPress function  to compare with.

Comment: I don't think you tested this, if you did how is your : getting through ? syntax error, unexpected ':'. All I did was copy and paste.

Comment: Update with "?"... the idea is that the WP function requires the value, not True or False... (condition)?value1:value2 is the PHP "Ternary Operator" http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: please make sure to run your code through an IDE. Your not getting syntax error on [ after the ?, unexpected '['

Comment: updated the code, I haven't time to reproduce your environment to test in IDE, my reply was intended for you get the idea of what was wrong calling the checked functions. In this case the variable $options was missing the $ at front, a simple typo that could be fixed by checking the code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check the value in the checked condition, not you're just checking if any value is being selected, which is always true after a submit

change

```
checked('display_rows', isset($options['display_rows']), false)
```

to:

```
checked('display_rows', isset($options['display_rows']) && $options['display_rows'] == 'display_rows', false),
```

and for the list to:

```
checked('display_rows', isset($options['display_rows']) && $options['display_rows'] == 'list', false),
```

Comment: You will see that I added the changes above in the OP. When I click any one, aside from the last radio element, only the last comes back as saved. You can see from the above code I am doing an echo statement, if I choose the 'display_rows' one I get display_rows printed yet 'no_posts' is the one selected. any other ideas?